# What does "bore" mean in the sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Experience teaches me that whatever a fellow-guest may have of power
>   to instruct or to amuse when he is sitting in a chair, or standing on
>   a hearth-rug, quickly leaves him when he takes one out for a walk. The
>   ideas that come so thick and fast to him in any room, where are they
>   now ? Where that encyclopedic knowledge which he **bore** so lightly?
>   Where the kindling fancy that played like summer lightning over any
>   topic that was started?

Is "bore" here a poetic way to say "dig the encyclopedic knowledge" or the past tense of "bear", or something else?

Comment: The phrasing is "poetic", but ***bore*** here is just a slightly fancier alternative to ***carried, held.*** The idea being that although the guy has all this (weighty, substantial) knowledge, he doesn't come across as ponderous / serious.

Answer (score 4):

In the context, the verb "bore" must be in the past tense. Therefore, the infinitive is [**"to bear"**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bear#cacd-1-2-1):

> bear (verb) (CARRY) = **to carry** or bring something:
>
> - *Fans bearing banners ringed the stadium.*

---

So the meaning of the sentence would be:

> What about the knowledge that he **carried** so lightly?